# How is the status of the site after the company's commitment to rebuild the relationship to the community released?

Tags: discussion

I heard that this site is going down after the exodus. However, the company has been trying to rebuild the relationship with community. How has this site been since then?

See: [The company’s commitment to rebuilding the relationship with you, our community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/260800)

Comment: It's a mess.  I'm doing basic moderation but nothing more.  The new announcement is just more of the same IMHO.  "Gosh we're sorry for messing up, but not sorry enough to actually fix anything we broke."

Comment: wait. I see that there are many actions to change?

Comment: From what I can see, codidact has siphoned off the site's already small number of active users, splitting it into two now entirely unsustainable sites.

Answer (score 4):

The majority of activity is still coming from 1-rep users. Off-topic questions are getting answered, and VLQ/NAA posts aren't getting deleted. None of those who left the site for Codidact have come back and I don't expect them to.

That announcement hasn't made the slightest bit of difference to Writing.SE, unfortunately.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't leave? (Just out of curiosity, I don't mean to be rude)

Comment: *Someone* has to stay here and try and keep some semblance of order. I'd hate to see the site turn into a total lawless wasteland.

Comment: There is a [successor site](https://writing.codidact.com/) where many of the people who left are active.  Everyone is welcome and questions get the attention they need.  (A new company meta post drew me back here today briefly.  Hi again, bye again.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio We know, this answer already mentioned it.